# What type of Object needs to be returned into await for it not being undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios, es6-promise

Let me be as clear as possible here.

1. I call the getVids function
2. It goes straight to its `return await Promise.all...`
3. Then it goes into recursion where `singleChannelWithNewVids` object is being dumped with `videos` array
4. When there is no more `res.data.nextPageToken` in response I'm returning that somewhat large `singleChannelWithNewVids` object.
5. My `console.log(singleChannelWithNewVids, 'RETURING')` line logs that this object exists
6. But when `const gettingVids = await getVidsWithPage(e)` happens and i log `console.log('gettingVids', gettingVids)` it logs that this object is undefined.

Why is that? I've tried everything as you can see commented and everyting returns undefined but logs a normal object...

```
const channelsWithPlaylistIds = [{
    channelName: 'TokyoStreetView - Japan The Beautiful',
    channelId: 'UCAxMEpfzdJ2dkrplSWehgcA',
    playlistIds: [ 'UUAxMEpfzdJ2dkrplSWehgcA' ],
    videos: []
}]

async getVids(channelsWithPlaylistIds) {
    const getVidsWithPage = async (e, pageToken) => {
        return axios(this.playlistItemsUrl(e.playlistIds[0], pageToken)).then(async res => {
            const singleChannelWithNewVids = { ...e, videos: [...e.videos, ...res.data.items]}

            if(res.data.nextPageToken) {
                console.log('RECUSING')
                await getVidsWithPage(singleChannelWithNewVids, res.data.nextPageToken)
            } else {
                console.log(singleChannelWithNewVids, 'RETURING')
                return Promise.resolve(singleChannelWithNewVids)
                // return new Promise(resolve => { resolve(singleChannelWithNewVids) })
                // return Promise.all([singleChannelWithNewVids])
                // return singleChannelWithNewVids
            }
        })
    }

    return await Promise.all(channelsWithPlaylistIds.map(async e => {
        const gettingVids = await getVidsWithPage(e)
        console.log('gettingVids', gettingVids)
        return gettingVids
    }))
}
```

*yes i don't use semicolon, it's 2020, deal with it*

Comment: Not using semicolons has nothing to do with 2020.  If you use a code uglifier/minimizer (which you should for productional code), you run the risk of introducing logic issues if you do not use semicolons.

Comment: @Taplar have you read the question? I know what exactly what problems I can run into. That sentence supposed to be a little joke. Please don't lecture others on things they didn't ask, you should better help them with the thing they need help with...

Comment: If you want to avoid soliciting feedback to a statement, consider not including the statement.

Comment: Are you sure you need the `await` in `const gettingVids = await getVidsWithPage(e)`?

Comment: @haim770 I think so... Its receiving a bunch of requests dependant on previous response data for a specific array inside a map function. I haven't found more elegant solution for this propblem at least.

Comment: @F1ks3r Regarding that and haim's comment, see my edited answer for some improvements. :)

Comment: @Klaycon thanks, i've missed the fact that i had `then()` for some reason i couldn't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a *recursive* function that *does not return* in all cases except the last.

To understand this, imagine the thread of execution for the *first* execution of `getVidsWithPage`. It makes an `axios` call, sees that `if(res.data.nextPageToken)` is true, enters that if-statement, and then calls a function (itself in this case, but this is not actually important) and then ends execution *without returning anything*.

During the recursion only the *very last* call to `getVidsWithPage` returns, but it returns to one of these:

```
await getVidsWithPage(singleChannelWithNewVids, res.data.nextPageToken)
```

...and the result is discarded.

Anyway, just add a `return` there:

```
return await getVidsWithPage(singleChannelWithNewVids, res.data.nextPageToken)
```

---

By the way, after seeing your comments, I'd like to suggest an unrelated improvement - YSK that *every* function marked `async` automatically, always returns a Promise. This is useful it means your `Promise.resolve` is redundant and you don't need to use `.then()` ever. You can rewrite your current code to be much more concise, like this:

```
getVids(channelsWithPlaylistIds) {
    const getVidsWithPage = async (e, pageToken) => {
        let res = await axios(this.playlistItemsUrl(e.playlistIds[0], pageToken))
        const singleChannelWithNewVids = { ...e, videos: [...e.videos, ...res.data.items]}

        if(res.data.nextPageToken) {
            console.log('RECUSING')
            return getVidsWithPage(singleChannelWithNewVids, res.data.nextPageToken)
        } else {
            console.log(singleChannelWithNewVids, 'RETURING')
            return singleChannelWithNewVids
        }
    }

    return Promise.all(channelsWithPlaylistIds.map(getVidsWithPage))
}
```